# struts2 jquery tree plugin 3.6.1 is not working on IE 7, 8 & 9

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, tree, struts2-jquery

I am creating a dynamic tree by using struts2-jquery-tree-plugin-3.6.1. The UI looking as a Tree Structure, but In IE on tree load the tree nodes are opening automatically on load of tree.

In Firefox and other browsers its working fine, I was used the 'openAllOnLoad="false"' tag also but no use. Below I have mentioned the my jsp tree structure code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="s2d"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjt" uri="/struts-jquery-tree-tags"%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="showcase" debug="false"/>
<sjt:tree id="bookId" 
cssClass="jqueryTree"
jstreetheme="apple"
rootNode="%{booksTree}" 
childCollectionProperty="booksList"
nodeTitleProperty="bookName" 
nodeIdProperty="bookId" 
value="%{bookId}"
label="bookName" 
name="bookName" 
onClickTopics="treeClicked" 
openAllOnLoad="false" />
```

On Firefox I can able to hide the child nodes but But in IE on load of tree elements it self automatically opens all the child nodes.

If anyone resolves this kind of problem earlier please guide me how to solve this problem.